# How to show images stock out product in programticallly magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

Product same as show as images in product page magento...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check product's stock status by this code on product list page

> $product->isSaleable()

By using above code you can add a class on that's product `<li>` e.g.

```
<li class="<?php if(!$product->isSaleable()){ echo 'outofstock';} ?>">
```

Now you can add image on this using css.
Here is css but need to adjust according to your need.

```
.products-grid .product-image { 
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    width: 244px; 
    height: 156px; 
    margin: 0 0 10px;
 }
    .outofstock{
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 20px;
        width: 65px;
        height: 66px;
        display: block;
        z-index: 2;
        background: url(../images/showcase.png) no-repeat;
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: what the css  file edit ...

Comment: @AshvinMonpara I have added the css but need to some tweaks

Comment: what css file i have edit..please explain...

Comment: @AshvinMonpara  in your theme's css

Comment: not display images.....

Comment: Is "outofstock" class showing in li ? is above css coming ? check with firebug

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51226/discussion-between-ashvin-monpara-and-arunendra).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51234/discussion-between-ashvin-monpara-and-arunendra).